# Get instances of running MS Flow Approval Workflow using Rest API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, powerapps, power-automate

I am looking for APIs to get list of run instances of a workflow on SharePoint Online.

From Microsoft documentation I can get list of workflows in the tenant.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/web-api

I would like to get all running workflows of a particular workflow, not only assigned to me

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware that Web API does not have an entity for the cloud flow runs (only the desktop flow ones, which is the flowsession entity).

However, you should still be able to use the Service.flow.microsoft.com approach.

For example Stefan Strube has a nice blog on how to create a custom connector for this:
https://2die4it.com/2020/07/08/custom-connector-to-get-flow-run-history/

[image]